# Passing a windows path to a vbs script which then runs a batch file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm trying to run a batch file hidden. I have read many threads here but I still can't get it working. Win7 - I have created a new toolbar in the taskbar that shows me all .enc files in a specific folder. I want to click to select one of those filenames and have it sent to the vbs script that will run a batch file hidden with that filename as the first argument for the batch file. I am using total commander and have set up a file association of the below for .enc files -

```
hidebat.vbs %1
```

That is supposed to take the filename I selected and send it to the script.

This is the script hidebat.vbs -

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "G:\test\clipTest.bat" WScript.Arguments(0), 0, True
```

That is from another thread on this topic to run batch files hidden but with my addition of the WScript.Arguments(0) part. Supposedly that grabs the first argument to the vbs script.

When I try this out I get a window stating that the filename I selected is not a valid win32 application. Is it obvious what's wrong?

If it all could be done within the vbs script, all the better. I'm only doing two things in the batch file -

```
1. echo|set /p=%1|clip  (echoing that filename to the clipboard)
2. start "" "g:\test\Process.lnk"  (running this shortcut)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [About using Double quotes in Vbscript](//stackoverflow.com/a/15771551)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `&` as well as a space between the script and your argument.
Try this:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "G:\test\clipTest.bat " & WScript.Arguments(0), 0, True
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.  Chr(34) resolves to a quote, in case your paths contain spaces:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run chr(34) & "G:\test\clipTest.bat" & chr(34) & " " & chr(34) & WScript.Arguments(0) & chr(34), 0, True
```

Comment: I'm still getting that error of not a Win32 application with both above answers.

Comment: ....then I would imagine it's a problem with your bat file and/or the argument that you're passing.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my file association line to  -

```
wscript "g:\path\to\hidebat.vbs" "%1"
```

Now it works, thanks!